Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. Net project
So I have been trying to implement a google calendar meeting assignments specifically for authenticated user.
Here is how it goes:
I have a Vite React.JS project with google auth implemented (it can sign in with google auth, gets access tokens and user related data)
Also, there is a .NET project where I am implementing a google calendar meeting assignments functionality. A user provides date and time in the request, it sents to backend and creates a slot for user. Also, I want to create a google meeting.
Here is how it goes:
So I created a google controller:
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Prospecting.WebApi.Controllers.V1
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class GoogleCalendarController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IGoogleCalendarService _googleCalendarService;

        public GoogleCalendarController(IGoogleCalendarService googleCalendarService)
        {
            _googleCalendarService = googleCalendarService;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateEvent([FromBody] Event request,
            [FromHeader(Name = "Authorization")] string accessTokenHeader,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessTokenHeader))
            {
                return Unauthorized("Access token is required.");
            }

            var createdEvent = await _googleCalendarService.CreateEvent(accessTokenHeader, request, cancellationToken);
            return Ok(createdEvent);
        }
    }
}

Here is a simple google service
using Prospecting.Business.Abstractions;
using Prospecting.Contracts;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;

namespace Prospecting.Business.Implementations;

public class GoogleCalendarService : IGoogleCalendarService
{
    private readonly IGoogleCalendarSettings _settings;

    public GoogleCalendarService(IGoogleCalendarSettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }

    public async Task<Event> CreateEvent(string accessToken, Event request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var credential = GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken(accessToken);

        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = _settings.ApplicationName,
        });

        var newEvent = new Event
        {
            Summary = request.Summary,
            Location = request.Location,
            Description = request.Description,
            Start = new EventDateTime
            {
                DateTime = request.Start.DateTime,
                TimeZone = request.Start.TimeZone,
            },
            End = new EventDateTime
            {
                DateTime = request.End.DateTime,
                TimeZone = request.End.TimeZone,
            }
        };

        var createdEvent = await service.Events.Insert(newEvent, "primary").ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
        return createdEvent;
    }
}

However, any time I want to create a google meeting:
Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential

This error pops up. I am sending exactly the same access token I get when a user is logged in into my React.JS project.
